# Closures on multiple instances

Tags: javascript, closures

Context: I am creating mouseovers to dynamically scroll through the images on an image post on a news feed. (i.e. there are multiple image posts on one page).

Post structure for multi-image:

```
.images {
   .leftArrow
   .left
   .center
   .right
   .rightArrow
}
```

For a single image it has the same but left and right are not present.

I am creating a mouseover closure which puts a mouseover on a leftArrow to cycle images. This should only work if there is a "left" image present.

```
// Gets first element with given class name
function getChildByClass(el, className) {
var notes = null;
var children = el.children;
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if ( children[i].classList.contains(className) ) {
      notes = children[i];
      break;
    }        
}
return notes;
}

// mouseover function
function spinLeft() {
var parents = $(".images");
for ( var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++ ) {
    var parent = parents[i];
    var arrow = getChildByClass(parent, "leftArrow");
    var index = getChildByClass(parent, "left");
    if ( index != null ) {
        arrow.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
            swapImages(this.parent, getChildByClass(this.parent, "left"));
        });
    }
}
}
spinLeft();

/* Post Usage: Spin algorithm for images */
function swapImages(parent, index) { // do swivel }
```

My problem is that when I do to "mouseover" the arrow, it does not have the correct value passing to swapImages. i.e. how would I do this so that I get the correct parent of the arrow? Another implementation I had gave me the last arrow, index variables that went through the loop. So I need something that uses, "this" element.

Open to any suggestions.

Comment: I suggest you check out [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) which would let you find the first child with a particular class without requiring another function.

Comment: @Pointy This gives me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'children' of object #<HTMLDivElement> is not a function `

Comment: It's a **jQuery** function: `$(this).children('.left').eq(0)` gets the first child element with class "left" starting from a DOM node referenced by `this`

Comment: Awesome thnk you, make it an answer and I'll give you the green

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$(".images")` indicates jQuery, then ...

Doing everything in jQuery, the following is directly equivalent to the code in the question (without the `function spinLeft(){...}` wrapper, which is unnecessary unless `spinLeft()` needs to be called more than once) :

```
$('.images').each(function(i, parent) {
    if ( $(parent).find('.left').length > 0 ) {
        $(parent).find('.leftArrow').on('mouseover', function() {
            swapImages(parent, $(parent).find('.left').get(0));
        });
    }
});
```

However, it's simpler to attach the `mouseover` handlers to the `.leftArrow` elements unconditionally then test for the presence of a sibling `.left` element inside the handler :

```
$('.images .leftArrow').on('mouseover', function(event) {
    var $left = $(this).siblings('.left');
    if ( $left.length > 0 ) {
        swapImages($(this).closest('.images').get(0), $left.get(0));
    }
});
```

If you are prepared to modify `swapImages()` to accept jQuery objects rather than raw node references, then :

```
$('.images .leftArrow').on('mouseover', function(event) {
    var $left = $(this).siblings('.left');
    if ( $left.length > 0 ) {
        swapImages($(this).closest('.images'), $left);
    }
});
```

If you are prepared to modify `swapImages()` to accept jQuery objects and be tolerant to empty jQuery objects, then :

```
$('.images .leftArrow').on('mouseover', function(event) {
    swapImages($(this).closest('.images'), $(this).siblings('.left'));
});
```